# Trimming sublists

Tags: python, list

I have a list `normalized_result_lists` containing sublists. For each sublist, I want to identify the first 10 unique elements and trim upto that element. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
normalized_result_lists = [
    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0012468827930174, 1.0024937655860349, 1.0049875311720697, 1.0087281795511223,
    1.0112219451371571, 1.0187032418952617, 1.0224438902743143, 1.0286783042394014,
    1.0299251870324189, 2.0, 3.0],
    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0013812154696133, 1.0013812154696133, 1.0055248618784531, 1.0055248618784531,
    1.0055248618784531, 1.0096685082872927, 1.0138121546961325, 1.0179558011049723,
    1.020718232044199, 1.0248618784530388, 1.031767955801105, 1.0414364640883977,
    1.0524861878453038, 1.0607734806629834, 1.0662983425414365]
]

unique_elements = set()
trimmed_lists = []

for lst in normalized_result_lists:
    trimmed_list = []
    for elem in lst:
        trimmed_list.append(elem)
        unique_elements.add(elem)

        if len(unique_elements) == 10:
            break

    trimmed_lists.append(trimmed_list)

print(trimmed_lists)
```

The current output is

```
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0012468827930174, 1.0024937655860349, 1.0049875311720697, 1.0087281795511223, 1.0112219451371571, 1.0187032418952617, 1.0224438902743143, 1.0286783042394014, 1.0299251870324189], [1.0]]
```

The expected output is

```
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0012468827930174, 1.0024937655860349, 1.0049875311720697, 1.0087281795511223, 1.0112219451371571, 1.0187032418952617, 1.0224438902743143, 1.0286783042394014, 1.0299251870324189], 
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0013812154696133, 1.0013812154696133, 1.0055248618784531, 1.0055248618784531,
    1.0055248618784531, 1.0096685082872927, 1.0138121546961325, 1.0179558011049723,
    1.020718232044199]
```

Comment: I think your expected output is not correct, Because length of first list of expected out is 10 but for second list it is 7. **(only counting unique element)**

Comment: Your description is not the same as your expected output. I agree with @codester_09akaSharim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `unique_elements` to an empty set after each iteration of loop so do this

Also, *I think your expected output is not correct, Because length of first list of expected out is 10 but for second list it is 7. (only counting unique element).*

```py
normalized_result_lists = [
    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0012468827930174, 1.0024937655860349, 1.0049875311720697, 1.0087281795511223,
    1.0112219451371571, 1.0187032418952617, 1.0224438902743143, 1.0286783042394014,
    1.0299251870324189, 2.0, 3.0],
    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0013812154696133, 1.0013812154696133, 1.0055248618784531, 1.0055248618784531,
    1.0055248618784531, 1.0096685082872927, 1.0138121546961325, 1.0179558011049723,
    1.020718232044199, 1.0248618784530388, 1.031767955801105, 1.0414364640883977,
    1.0524861878453038, 1.0607734806629834, 1.0662983425414365]
]

trimmed_lists = []

for lst in normalized_result_lists:
    trimmed_list = []
    unique_elements = set() # For each iteration of outer loop setting unque element to empty set
    for elem in lst:
        trimmed_list.append(elem)
        unique_elements.add(elem)

        if len(unique_elements) == 10:
            break

    trimmed_lists.append(trimmed_list)

print(trimmed_lists)
```

Output

```
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 
1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0012468827930174, 1.0024937655860349, 1.0049875311720697, 
1.0087281795511223, 1.0112219451371571, 1.0187032418952617, 
1.0224438902743143, 1.0286783042394014, 1.0299251870324189], [1.0, 1.0,
 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 
1.0013812154696133, 1.0013812154696133, 1.0055248618784531, 
1.0055248618784531, 1.0055248618784531, 1.0096685082872927, 
1.0138121546961325, 1.0179558011049723, 1.020718232044199, 
1.0248618784530388, 1.031767955801105, 1.0414364640883977]]
```

Comment: The output does not match the expected output (as stated in the question) and yet has been accepted as the definitive answer

Comment: @CtrlZ I already commented this on OP's Post. _"I think your expected output is not correct, Because length of first list of expected out is 10 but for second list it is 7. (only counting unique element)"_

Answer (score 1):

use the following code:

```
result = []
for sub_list in normalized_result_lists:
    sub_result = []
    count = 0
    for val in sub_list:
        count += val not in sub_result
        sub_result.append(val)
        if count == 10: break
    result.append(sub_result)


[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 
  1.0012468827930174, 1.0024937655860349, 1.0049875311720697, 1.0087281795511223, 1.0112219451371571, 1.0187032418952617, 
  1.0224438902743143, 1.0286783042394014, 1.0299251870324189, 2.0], 
   [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0013812154696133, 1.0013812154696133, 1.0055248618784531, 1.0055248618784531, 1.0055248618784531, 1.0096685082872927, 
   1.0138121546961325, 1.0179558011049723, 1.020718232044199, 1.0248618784530388, 1.031767955801105, 1.0414364640883977, 1.0524861878453038]]
```

Note that if the data is sorted just like in your case, you could optimise further by just checking whether the current value is the same as the previous value. If not, increment count by 1. then break when count is 10

---

Edit:

To match the expected results use:

```
result = []
for sub_list in normalized_result_lists:
    sub_result = []
    count = 1
    for val in sub_list:
        if val == 1:
            sub_result.append(val)
        if val not in sub_result:
            sub_result.append(val)
            count += 1
        if count == 10: break
    result.append(sub_result)

results
```

Comment: This does not produce OP's expected output

Comment: @CtrlZ the OP expected result is quite confusing. The first sublist has 10 unique values while the 2nd one has 7 unique values. Either allowed duplicates or remove duplicates. This code allows duplicates and matches the results from the accepted solution